# How do I convert JSON data types to matching C# types

Tags: c#, json, windows, windows-runtime

I was trying to build data into a Windows 8.1 app using the Grid App template. I followed the SampleDataSource.cs and the SampleData.json pattern, I modified it to suit the kind of data and items my app should have. there is a GetMediaDataAsync method whose code is below, I was getting some errors.

```js
private async Task GetMediaDataAsync()
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            if (this._groups.Count != 0)
                return;
            Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/MediaData.json");

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
            string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

            foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
            {
                JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
                MediaDataGroup group = new MediaDataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                    groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                    groupObject["ShortTitle"].GetString(),
                    groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                    groupObject["Description"].GetString());

                foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
                {
                    JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                    group.Items.Add(new MediaDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["BackgroundImage"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["TitleImage"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["Duration"].GetNumber(),
                        itemObject["Author"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["ReleaseDate"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["Format"].GetString(),
                        itemObject["PurchaseLink"].GetString()));
                }
                this.Groups.Add(group);
            }
        }
```

The lines that gives error are :

1. `itemsObject["ReleaseDate"].GetString();` says could not convert string to Datetime
2. `itemsObject["Duration"].GetNumber()` says could not convert Double to int
3. `itemsObject["PurchaseLink"].GetString()` says could not convert string to Uri

can someone help me with the right way to do it so that I don't get these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all fields as `string`, but you should convert them to appropriate types:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(itemObject["ReleaseDate"])
Convert.ToInt32(itemObject["Duration"].GetNumber())
new Uri(itemObject["PurchaseLink"].GetString())
```

Comment: Immediately I did this all red lines were removed, though I haven't used the data. I am happy about it, I hate red underlines in Visual Studio I didn't even think in that direction. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to a `DateTime` you would parse it, for example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(itemsObject["ReleaseDate"].GetString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

A number in JSON is always a `double`, so to get it as an `int` you just cast it:

```
(int)(itemsObject["Duration"].GetNumber())
```

To create an `Uri` object from a string, you use its constructor:

```
new Uri(itemsObject["PurchaseLink"].GetString())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the string content of the Json object you can convert it to a Type of your definition using any Json Library, I suggest you to use Newton.Json

Examle

Json:

```
{"Name":"MyName","Family":[{"Name":"MyBro Name","Rel":"Brother"}],"Age":15}
```

C# Types:

```
class FamilyMember{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Rel{get;set;} 
}
class Person{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public FamilyMember [] Family{get;set;}
}
```

And here is usage Example

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
var name = person.Name;
var age= person.Age;
```